# Customized Hash Function based on cardinality

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I would like to develop a hash function that receives a BitSet object and generates the hash value based on the number of 1 in the BitSet. This number is calculated using:

```
BitSet b = new Bitset();
int card = b.cardinality();
```

For example:

```
110
1
010
111
```

I would like a Map that return the elements in this order:

```
1
010
110
111
```

or

```
010
1
110
111
```

Io ho provato una soluzione utilizzando TObjectIntCustomHashMap:

```
map = new TObjectIntCustomHashMap<BitSet>( new HashingStrategy<BitSet>() {
            @Override
            public int computeHashCode( BitSet str ) {
                return System.identityHashCode( str );
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals( BitSet str1, BitSet str2 ) {
                return (str1.cardinality() < str2.cardinality());
            }
        });
```

but the result is not as expected.

Comment: Okay, so what's your question? The implementation does not seem to be very hard, what exactly are stuck on? Did you try something that gave an unexpected result?

Comment: You want a "map that returns the elements in this order", so if you want an ordered map use a `TreeSet` and then make an object encapsulating your `card` and then override the `compareTo()` function

Comment: He seems to want to integrate this into a `Map` structure, in Java, you can't have a custom `hashCode` function except by favouring composition over inheritance

Comment: @MathBunny Also he can simply pass a `Comparator` object to the constructor of the `TreeMap`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @MathBunny I don't want to use an ordered map because I want to reduce complexity with a custom hash function.

Comment: Complexity in terms of code or time? You can't really sort in sub O(nlogn) time, and in terms of code @user9335240's suggestion is very clean, especially with Java8 Lambdas

Comment: HashMap is not guaranteed to order its keys in hash order.

Comment: @MathBunny Complexity in terms of time. If I put my element on the map with a hash function that makes this sorting indirect, I should improve the complexity.

Comment: Try adding a few random Integers into a HashMap. The Integer hashCode is the value of the integer itself. Iterate over the map and you'll see that they don't come out sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I think the cleanest solution, building from user93335240 is to apply a custom comparator to a `TreeSet` allowing for an `O(nlogn)` solution like this:

```
Set<Integer> t = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> { a.cardinality() - b.cardinality() });
t.forEach((a) -> System.out.println(a));
```

Where you would create your own wrapper to provide the `cardinality()` functionality.

You cannot use hashing because it doesn't guarantee the distribution of hashCode values when there's collisions. You can try something like linear probing but it would not gurantee that it would be correct.

In fact, this would be [disproving the lower bound on the comparison sort based model](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf) if you were to get a sub `O(nlogn)` solution.

Answer (score 0):

to answer to you even i think that @MathBunny is right ... its better to use dedicated structure that handle your requirement than use a side effect of current implem of hashmap... here is what you search

```
public class HashTest {
    public static class BitSet extends java.util.BitSet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4014851086683360760L;

        public BitSet(int i) {
            super(i);
        }

        public BitSet() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return stream().map(i -> (int) Math.pow(2, i)).sum();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof java.util.BitSet) {
                return obj == null ? false : obj.hashCode() == hashCode();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

//  1
//  010
//  110
//  111
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitSet bitset1 = new BitSet(1);
        bitset1.set(0);
        BitSet bitset2 = new BitSet(3);
        bitset2.set(1);
        BitSet bitset3 = new BitSet(3);
        bitset3.set(1);
        bitset3.set(2);
        BitSet bitset4 = new BitSet(3);
        bitset4.set(0);
        bitset4.set(1);
        bitset4.set(2);
        Map<BitSet, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(bitset1, "bitset1");
        map.put(bitset2, "bitset2");
        map.put(bitset3, "bitset3");
        map.put(bitset4, "bitset4");
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(v));

    }

}
```

Comment: HashMaps don't always store entries in hashcode order. Also, the hashcode in your answer is not the one the OP requires (he only wants it to equal the cardinality, i.e. just the number of bits set, not the integer representation of the bitset).

Comment: I am completely right with you order is just a side effect of current hash map implementation this is completely going out if your are using large number (on more that 32 bits) but in J8 this work on smal data ... that what he asks for... i am completely agree with you that its not safe and not a good pratice at all!

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec Thanks for your help, but if I put  001 and 010 the hashCode produces the same value and the elements overlap. This is a problem.

Comment: eu nop .... 
  BitSet bit0 = new BitSet(3);
  bit0.set(0, false);
  bit0.set(1,true);
  bit0.set(2,false);
  BitSet bit1 = new BitSet(3);
  bit1.set(0, true);
  bit1.set(1,false);
  bit1.set(2,false);
  
  System.out.println(bit0 +" "+bit0.hashCode());
  System.out.println(bit1 +" "+bit1.hashCode());
this display {1} 2
{0} 1

Comment: the hascode compute the value of the bit set as unsign integer